# Button text change from another activity

Tags: button, android-intent, android-activity, onclick, click

I'm having problem in changing the text of a button in main activity. I want to change the text of that button upon click on another button which is in second activity. Please help me with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it but simplest way to do it is- You can maintain a static boolean variable in any of your activity and change its value to true on the button click of your other activity and whenever your AainActivity resumes you can check in its onResume() method for this variable and if it is true -> change the text of your button in MainActivity.

Comment: Ambujesh.. i want to confirm that if the text of that button gets changes.. i want that change to be permanent untill and unless i uninstall that app..